# How to run flask website on apache2 at my own pc ip address 192.168.x.x

Tags: python, apache, ubuntu, flask, webdeploy

I have created a flask web application and i successfully run using flask run. Then after, i installed apache2 server in my ubuntu 14.04. I tried to deploy flask app on apache2 server. I have done this and i can access my app on 127.0.0.1 or using server name 'localhost'.

my virtualhost setting is
/etc/apache2/sites-available/hello.conf

```
 <virtualhost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    WSGIDaemonProcess hello user=vishnumc group=vishnumc threads=5 home=/var/www/FlaskApp/
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/FlaskApp/hello.wsgi

    <directory /var/www/FlaskApp>
        WSGIProcessGroup hello
        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
        WSGIScriptReloading On
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </directory>
</virtualhost>
```

my wsgi file is
/var/www/FlaskApp/hello.wsgi

```
activate_this = '/home/vishnumc/vishnu/project/env/bin/activate_this.py'
execfile(activate_this, dict(__file__=activate_this))
import sys

sys.path.insert(0,"/home/vishnumc/vishnu/project/flask/testapp")

from hello import app as application
```

My flask web app is
/home/vishnumc/vishnu/project/flask/testapp/hello.py

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return '<h1>This is your index...</h1>'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

My hosts file is
/etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       vishnumc-P452LA

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

Can anyone help me to access my web app (above) at my own IP address 192.168.1.4 local lan. When i tried using this address, it shows default page of apache2.

Please help me?
I want to know how virtual host work? please help me? i am new to apache and flask.

Can apache listen to both 127.0.0.1 and 192.168.1.4 address? since i got default page at both address during the installation test of apache (before using flask app) ?

Answer (score 0):

Please add the following line in `/etc/hosts`

```
0.0.0.0    192.168.1.4
```

Hope this will works.

Please let me know in terms of any queries.

Comment: Sorry, its not working. it shows the same default apache page.

Comment: Initially your IP address was bind with port no 80. So please try using port 5000, which is default for flask.

Comment: Not, it has no result

Answer (score 0):

#### Why apache shows default page only

If you access the server via the external IP address, the Apache server will deal with the request based on its default site configuration, returning the default page of Apache.

If you want to access the server via the external IP address, you have to disable the default site configuration first.

```
sudo a2dissite 000-default.conf
service apache2 restart
```

#### Why 127.0.0.1 and 192.168.1.4 show the same page

127.0.0.1 and 192.168.1.4 are both the IP address of server. The 127.0.0.1 is loopback address, representing this computer. A loopback address is a non-routable IP address that is defined as referring to the "local" computer. It's used when the computer wants to access itself.

192.168.1.4 is a local network address, which is used by other computers or network devices to find your computer, like the street No.

If you access a server via IP address only, you are accessing Port 80. Apache listens to this port by default and will return its default test page if request received.